# GTK+3 C gtk_label_set_use_markup for a GtkButton + CSS style

Tags: css, gtk3

I'm porting a GTK+2 based application to GTK+3 on Ubuntu 16.  I'm trying to set the markup for the label of a button but it seems something has been deprecated.  Here is the original code:

```
gtk_label_set_use_markup(GTK_LABEL(GTK_BIN(button)->child), TRUE);
```

GCC now complains that GTK_BIN doesn't have a member 'child'.  So is there another technique I can use to do this?  I've really struggled to find any useful information on this.

Related to this...I'm also looking for a WORKING example of using CSS to setup widget styles for a GTK+3 app.  The current app uses gtk_widget_override_background_color() which is now deprecated.  It seems the only way to control color is with CSS but I can't seem to glue the pieces together yet.  I need to setup different colors for different widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and experimentation found a solution to part of the problem.  This works to set the markup of a button label as long as the label is the only child of the button widget:

```
gtk_label_set_use_markup(GTK_LABEL( gtk_bin_get_child( GTK_BIN(button) ) ), TRUE);
```

I still have not found a way to dynamically control the background color of a label or button widget using styles.